# I have installed the grails appengine plugin, I use intellij, how can I get intellj to quit yelling at me for jdo errors?

Tags: google-app-engine, grails, intellij-idea

So,

I am trying to integrate a grails app, with google app engine, all using intellij. I successfully built the grails app, and I installed the app engine plugin successfully. But, now all my domain classes have JDO errors.

Intellij has built in support for app engine, but I couldn't quickly figure out a way to integrate it with my grails app. So I just used the grails command line.

Ideally I would like to use the intellij plugin, but at this point I just want the errors to disappear.

How do I get my jdo errors to go away in my intellij grails app?

And if your feeling really helpful:
How do I use the intellij app engine module to integrate with my grails app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of the error or a screenshot? If it's an inspection you can disable it via an intention action shortcut (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) while standing on the code with an error/warning. When menu opens, press the right arrow for the sub-menu where you can disable it. If it's a result of language injection feature, you can try to un-inject the language using the same intention action.

[Feel free to vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-48543) for the built-in Grails App Engine support in IntelliJ IDEA.